# Упаковка большого количества чисел, сжатый массив битовых чисел

Tags: битовые-операции, массивы, c++

**Есть данный код, который упаковывает число в число (пример в комментарии), проблема в битовом сдвиге, даже если значение конкретно в строке:**

```
  //Упаковка в 16 бит\число
unsigned setnum(const unsigned &pack, const char &hiegth_bit_max_dec, const unsigned &num, const unsigned &wordnum)
{
    unsigned count_words = wordnum*hiegth_bit_max_dec;
    count_words %= int(floor(16 / hiegth_bit_max_dec)*hiegth_bit_max_dec);
    unsigned maskword = ((1 << hiegth_bit_max_dec) - 1) << count_words;//создаем маску числа на место слова
    cout << ((wordnum*hiegth_bit_max_dec) % count_words)<< '=' << endl <<bitset<32>(maskword) << endl;
    maskword ^= (1 << 16) - 1; //переворачиваем маску
    return ((pack & maskword) | (num << (wordnum*hiegth_bit_max_dec)));
};

//Распаковка из 16 бит\число
unsigned getnum(const unsigned &pack, const char &hiegth_bit_max_dec, const unsigned &wordnum)
{
    unsigned count_words = wordnum*hiegth_bit_max_dec;
    count_words %= int(floor(16 / hiegth_bit_max_dec)*hiegth_bit_max_dec);
    unsigned maskword = ((1 << hiegth_bit_max_dec) - 1) << (count_words);//создаем маску числа на место слова
    return ((pack & maskword) >> (wordnum*hiegth_bit_max_dec));//очищаем все по маске, кроме слова, сдвигаем и получаем число
};
```

**Ошибку нашел и привел по совету https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd  и получился вот такой код основных функций (ошибка была в сдвиге, но не в том что я проверял):**

```
const size_t bits_in_byte = 8;
const size_t bits_in_variable = sizeof(unsigned)* bits_in_byte;
//Упаковка в bits_in_variable бит\число
void setnum(unsigned &pack, const char &hiegth_bit_max_dec, const unsigned &num, const unsigned &wordnum)
{
    unsigned count_words = wordnum*hiegth_bit_max_dec;
    count_words %= int(floor(bits_in_variable / hiegth_bit_max_dec)*hiegth_bit_max_dec);
    unsigned maskword = ((1 << hiegth_bit_max_dec) - 1) << count_words;//создаем маску числа на место слова
    maskword ^= (1 << bits_in_variable) - 1; //переворачиваем маску
    pack = ((pack & maskword) | (num << count_words));
};

//Распаковка из bits_in_variable бит\число
unsigned getnum(const unsigned &pack, const char &hiegth_bit_max_dec, const unsigned &wordnum)
{
    unsigned count_words = wordnum*hiegth_bit_max_dec;
    count_words %= int(floor(bits_in_variable / hiegth_bit_max_dec)*hiegth_bit_max_dec);
    unsigned maskword = ((1 << hiegth_bit_max_dec) - 1) << (count_words);//создаем маску числа на место слова
    return ((pack & maskword) >> (count_words));//очищаем все по маске, кроме слова, сдвигаем и получаем число
};
```

**основная функция демонстрирующая работу упаковщика (ввести кол-во чисел которые будем упаковывать и максимальное число для упаковки)**

```
int main()
{
    unsigned n, maxd;

    cout << "Enter count of Dec="; cin >> n; cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Maximum Dec="; cin >> maxd; cout << endl;
    cout << "MAX Bit=" << (hibit(maxd)) << "\tof\tMAX Number=" << maxd << endl;

    int count_words_in_variable = bits_in_variable / hibit(maxd);

    unsigned *arrayn = new unsigned[n / (count_words_in_variable) + n % (count_words_in_variable)];
    cout << n / (count_words_in_variable) + n % (count_words_in_variable) << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < (n / (count_words_in_variable) + n % (count_words_in_variable)); i++)
        arrayn[i] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (n); i++)
        setnum(arrayn[int(floor(i / (count_words_in_variable)))], hibit(maxd), maxd, i);

    for (int i = 0; i < (n); i++)
    {
        cout << getnum((arrayn[int(floor(i / (count_words_in_variable)))]), hibit(maxd), i) << '=';
        cout << int(floor(i / (count_words_in_variable))) << " in ";
        cout << bitset <bits_in_variable>(arrayn[int(floor(i / (count_words_in_variable)))]) << endl;
    };

    delete []  arrayn;

    system("pause>>void");
    return 0;
};
```

**ну и конечно все это выделено в отдельный класс:**

```
class packetbit
{
private:
    size_t *_arrayns; //Array
    size_t _sizearray;//Size of Array
    size_t _word;       //count words in bits_in_variable bits
    char _size_word_in_bit;     //Size of Word
    size_t _count; //need to write all words

    //Размер числа в битах учитывая младшие
    friend int hibit(const unsigned &num);

    //Упаковка в bits_in_variable бит\число
    friend void setnum(unsigned &pack, const char &hiegth_bit_max_dec, const unsigned &num, const unsigned &wordnum);

    //Распаковка из bits_in_variable бит\число
    friend unsigned getnum(const unsigned &pack, const char &hiegth_bit_max_dec, const unsigned &wordnum);

public:
    packetbit(const unsigned &SizeArray, const unsigned MaxDec)
    {
        _sizearray = SizeArray;
        _size_word_in_bit = hibit(MaxDec);
        _word = floor(bits_in_variable / _size_word_in_bit);
        _count = (_sizearray / _word + _sizearray % _word);
        _arrayns = new size_t [_count];
        for (int I = 0; I < _count; I++) _arrayns[I] = 0;
    };

    ~packetbit()
    {
        delete [] _arrayns;
    };

    //записывает в bits_in_variable бит \ число
    void setn(const unsigned &num, const unsigned &wordnum)
    {
        setnum(_arrayns[int(floor(wordnum / _word))], _size_word_in_bit, num, wordnum);
    };
    //считывает из bits_in_variable бит \ число
    unsigned getn(const unsigned &wordnum)
    {
        return getnum(_arrayns[int(floor(wordnum / _word))], _size_word_in_bit, wordnum);
    };
};
```

Comment: Кстати, `_word = 16 / _sword;` кажется мне очень подозрительным. Не нужно ли на самом деле `_word = _sword / 16;`? Например, если `MaxDec` больше 16-ти бит, `_word` будет просто 0. А вы на него делите потом.

---
Кстати, вы сами себя запутываете, давая переменным слишком короткие имена. `_sword` — это меч, что ли? Нет, надо держать в голове, что это `_size_of_word`. Почему бы тогда так и не назвать?

Comment: Смотрите. Обычно делают так:

    const size_t bits_in_byte = 8;
    const size_t bits_in_word = (sizeof(unsigned) / sizeof(char)) * bits_in_byte;

    size_t word_number_for(size_t n) { return n / bits_in_word; }
    size_t bit_number_in_word_for(size_t n) { return n % bits_in_word; }

    unsigned mask_for(size_t n) { return 1u << bit_number_in_word_for(n); }

    // ссылка важна!
    unsigned& word_for(size_t n) { return _arrayns[word_number_for(n)]; }

    public:
    void setbit(size_t n) { word_for(n) |= mask_for(n); }

и т. д. Таким образом вы абстрагируетесь от размера слова.

Comment: Разумеется, «переворачивать» биты лучше так:

    void unsetbit(size_t n) { word_for(n) &= ~mask_for(n); }

Обратите снимание, что в `mask_for` единица записана как `1u`, то есть сразу нужного типа (`unsigned`).

Comment: все бы хорошо и да мы уходим, но по условию и примеру в условии:
> Например, если мы знаем, что диапазон хранимых
значений 0..7, то для сохранения значения необходимо всего 3 бита."
и соответственно теряется это :> Количество бит на значение(максимум 16) должно определятся автоматически при выделении памяти под таблицу.

Comment: @Иван Корнев: А в чём проблема? Ничего не теряется, вы просто правильно подсчитываете нужный размер массива:

    size_t required_bits = (size_t)ceil(log(maxval) / log(2));
    size_t required_words = (size_t)ceil((double)required_bits / bits_in_word);
    _arrayns = new unsigned[required_words];

(Обратите внимание, `ceil` вроде бы правильнее, чем прибавить единицу. Но перепроверьте крайние случаи, я могу и ошибаться.)

---
Кстати, тут лимит комментариев (4 шт. на каждый вопрос и каждый из ответов), так что при надобности удаляйте старые.

Comment: @Иван Корнев: Кстати, вы не сможете выделить под данные _ровно_ три бита, так как

 * минимальная единица выделения памяти — байт, то есть 8 бит, так что можно выделить лишь кратно восьми
 * если выделять целыми словами, то кратно размеру слова
 * реально при выделении _X_ байт выделяется больше, но эти «лишние» байты вам не доступны: в них хранится служебная информация менеджера памяти.

Comment: а вот в том то и дело что я знаю что минимум который может быть это 
>1 байт = 8 бит = 255(10)

но мне нужно его именно упаковать одно в другое для экономии места т.е.
>в двоичном виде 
00000001|00000010|00000011|00000100|00000101|00000110 
нам нужно все 3 бита:
001|010|011|100|101|110 
теперь соединяем в массив char 
00101001|11001011|10000000 
или в десятичном виде 
41 203 128 
вот то что нужно.

Comment: @Иван Корнев: Хм. Добавил код в ответ.

Comment: @Иван Корнев: О, новый код, хорошо. А работает для случая, когда размер записи не кратен размеру слова? Или вы оставляете неиспользуемые биты?

Comment: да работает, к примеру для случая в 3 бита\слово где будет использовано 30 бит из 32-х, изначально в этом то и состояла задача. Сейчас нужно переписать все это дело в класс, но уже радует что работает как задумано.

Comment: дописал, в шапку добавил код класса.
**На самом деле я думаю данный класс очень многим пригодится кому важны ресурсы или хотя-бы подход**
Теперь последний этап добавить все-возможные иключения т.н. защиту от дурака (отрицательные значения размера и т.д.)

Comment: @Иван Корнев: Ага, вижу. Но всё же, с подходом как в ответе можно использовать все 32 бита. За счёт немного большей сложности кода и небольшой просадки производительности.

---
Плюс к тому, размер записи с таким подходом не ограничен 32-мя битами, только бы в переменную какого-нибудь целочисленного типа влазил. (Можно и это ограничение обойти при желании.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А, теперь, кажется, понял. Я думал, что вам нужен упакованный массив *битов*, а вам нужна более сложная штука.

Тогда всё немного меняется. Вам нужно знать две вещи: какой длины ваше «слово», и какой длины ваша одна запись. (Например, слово = 32 бита, а запись = 3 бита). Теперь: запись *может* переходить через границу слова. В принципе, даже нескольких слов. Поэтому код получается примерно такой:

```
size_t bits_in_record;

// ======================
// входящие: size_t array_size_in_records, record_t maxval

typedef unsigned word_t;
typedef unsigned record_t;

const size_t bits_in_byte = 8;
const size_t bits_in_word = (sizeof(word_t) / sizeof(char)) * bits_in_byte;

bits_in_record = (size_t)ceil(log(maxval) / log(2));
const size_t array_size_in_bits = array_size_in_records * bits_in_record;
const size_t array_size_in_words =
                 (size_t)ceil((double)array_size_in_bits / bits_in_word);

_arrayns = new unsigned[required_words];

// ======================
// теперь операции
size_t start_bit_number_for_index(size_t n)
{
    return n * bits_in_record;
}

size_t start_word_number_for_index(size_t n)
{
    return start_bit_number_for_index(n) / bits_in_word;
}

size_t start_bit_number_in_word_for_index(size_t n)
{
    return start_bit_number_for_index(n) % bits_in_word;
}

public:
void setvalue(size_t index, word_t value)
{
    size_t word_index = start_word_number_for_index(index);
    size_t start_bit_number = start_bit_number_in_word_for_index(index);
    size_t remaining_bits = bits_in_record;

    while (remaining_bits > 0) // цикл по словам, которые содержат нашу запись
    {
        // мы не можем перенести за раз всё, мы упираемся в конец слова
        size_t end_bit_number = min(start_bit_number + remaining_bits, bits_in_word);
        // вот столько бит получится за эту итерацию:
        size_t number_of_bits_to_transfer = end_bit_number - start_bit_number;
        size_t mask = (((word_t)1) << number_of_bits_to_transfer) - 1;
        mask <<= start_bit_number;
        _arrayns[word_index] &= ~mask; // очистить старое значение
        _arrayns[word_index] |= (value << start_bit_number) & mask;
                                       // установить новое

        start_bit_number = 0; // после начального куска, начинаем от нулевого бита
        value >>= number_of_bits_to_transfer; // убираем переданные биты
        remaining_bits -= number_of_bits_to_transfer;
        word_index++;
    }
}

word_t getvalue(size_t index)
{
    record_t total_value = 0;

    size_t word_index = start_word_number_for_index(index);
    size_t start_bit_number = start_bit_number_in_word_for_index(index);
    size_t remaining_bits = bits_in_record;

    size_t target_bit = 0;

    while (remaining_bits > 0)
    {
        size_t end_bit_number = min(start_bit_number + remaining_bits, bits_in_word);
        size_t number_of_bits_to_transfer = end_bit_number - start_bit_number;
        size_t mask = (((word_t)1) << number_of_bits_to_transfer) - 1;
        mask <<= start_bit_number;

        record_t curr_value = (_arrayns[word_index] & mask) >> start_bit_number;

        total_value |= curr_value << target_bit;

        target_bit += number_of_bits_to_transfer;
        start_bit_number = 0; // после начального куска, начинаем от нулевого бита
        remaining_bits -= number_of_bits_to_transfer;
        word_index++;
    }

    return total_value;
}
```

Спрашивайте, надеюсь, переменные назвал понятно.

Comment: @Иван Корнев: обновил ответ, было неправильно в некоторых местах.

Comment: спасибо изучу внимательно код, попробую встроить в свой код, но задача была у меня самостоятельно написать код, вы мне помогли найти ошибку и осознать некоторые вещи, к примеру о названиях переменных.
Тут есть запись, нету чтения и по моему при таком способе взятия будет в несколько раз дольше вытаскивать значение, если оно будет находится разбито в соседние "упаковки".

Comment: @Иван Корнев: Сейчас напишу и чтение. В любом случае, очень хорошей идеей является написать код самостоятельно.

По поводу скорости: да, это правда. Но если значение помещается в одну «ячейку», будет сравнимо быстро.

Comment: @Иван Корнев: написал чтение. (Хотя наверняка в коде есть ошибки, я его не тестировал.)